# Finding the mode of an array

Tags: javascript, beginner, statistics

I am a beginner in JavaScript and just wanted to get my code reviewed. Here I have created a function that takes in an array and returns the mode. If there is no more then I just want the function to return the first number. It seems a little too long and I feel like there may be more clever ways to do it. Again, keep in mind that I am a beginner, so I don't have a huge toolbox.

```
var mode = function(arr){
    var numMapping = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(numMapping[arr[i]] === undefined){
            numMapping[arr[i]] = 0;
        }        
            numMapping[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
    var greatestFreq = 0;
    var mode;
    for(var prop in numMapping){
        if(numMapping[prop] > greatestFreq){
            greatestFreq = numMapping[prop];
            mode = prop;
        }
    }
    return parseInt(mode);
}
```

Comment: Mode (Average) from Rosetta Code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Mode#JavaScript

Comment: You don't have to do the second part of your code(finding the mode) *after* looping the array once already - you can do it during the mapping

Comment: Worth noting that there can be more than one mode in an array. Your code will just return the first-occurring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var mode = function(arr){
```

It's nice to name your functions for debugging purposes, if none other. You could replace this with a function declaration, e.g. `function mode(arr) {` or just name the function expression: `var mode = function mode(arr) {`

```
    var numMapping = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(numMapping[arr[i]] === undefined){
            numMapping[arr[i]] = 0;
        }        
            numMapping[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
```

I would use `arr.forEach()`, since it lets you operate on the elements directly. You could also make the mapping a one-liner(but both of these things are more nitpicks/personal style choice)

```
    var greatestFreq = 0;
    var mode;
    for(var prop in numMapping){
        if(numMapping[prop] > greatestFreq){
            greatestFreq = numMapping[prop];
            mode = prop;
        }
    }
    return parseInt(mode);
}
```

You can do this whole part during your first loop! Also, `parseInt`, while safe in this case, is not generally safe to use without a radix(you'd have linters complaining about this usage here). You could use `parseInt(mode, 10)`, or some ToNumber() transformation like `+mode`(http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6).

Here's a revised example:

```
var mode = function mode(arr) {
    var numMapping = {};
    var greatestFreq = 0;
    var mode;
    arr.forEach(function findMode(number) {
        numMapping[number] = (numMapping[number] || 0) + 1;

        if (greatestFreq < numMapping[number]) {
            greatestFreq = numMapping[number];
            mode = number;
        }
    });
    return +mode;
}
```

Comment: Unless you are golfing you should avoid stuff like `+mode`. While it's generally understood it is not as clear as `parseInt`. In your code there is no need to have `var mode = function[...]`. Either use `var mode =` or a function name, using both is superfluous. Also, having an inner and outer variable share the same name is generally bad. In this case `mode` is the name used for the function and inner variable.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, this is reasonable beginner's code.  And @Sacho's answer gives good suggestions for improving it.

Below is a solution using some slightly more advanced techniques, if you're interested:

```
var mode = function mode(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(current, item) {
        var val = current.numMapping[item] = (current.numMapping[item] || 0) + 1;
        if (val > current.greatestFreq) {
            current.greatestFreq = val;
            current.mode = item;
        }
        return current;
    }, {mode: null, greatestFreq: -Infinity, numMapping: {}}).mode;
};

console.log(mode([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6]));
//=> 3
```

To see how it works, if you drop off the `.mode` at the very end of the return, you will get this object instead:

```
{
    "mode": 3,
    "greatestFreq": 4,
    "numMapping": {"1": 2, "2": 2, "3": 4, "4": 2,
                   "5": 3, "6": 2, "7": 1, "8": 2, "9": 3}
}
```

This object is built up a piece at a time by the `reduce` call running over each element of the array, updating the `numMapping` each time and the `greatestFreq` and `mode` when appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

This is not bad at all. A few things can be simplified a bit.

---

When checking if `arr[i]` exists in `numMapping`:

> ```
> if(numMapping[arr[i]] === undefined){
> ```

A simpler and more natural way is this:

```
if (!(arr[i] in numMapping)) {
```

---

As a tiny optimization, instead of this:

> ```
> if (!(arr[i] in numMapping)) {
>     numMapping[arr[i]] = 0;
> }
> numMapping[arr[i]] += 1;
> ```

This is somewhat better:

```
if (!(arr[i] in numMapping)) {
    numMapping[arr[i]] = 1;
} else {
    numMapping[arr[i]] += 1;
}
```

Because this way you save one extra lookup of `arr[...]` and also `numMapping[...]`,
by directly assigning 1 instead of 0 and then incrementing later.

---

At a few places the indentation was off,
and I would recommend a bit more generous spaces in `if(...){` and `for(...){` statements, use `if (...) {` and `for (...) {` instead (like in my examples above).

Comment: Using `for (var i in arr)` is not always a good idea. `var arr = [1,2,3]; arr.test = "test"; for( var i in arr){ console.log( i, arr[i]); }` will log 4 things but the array length is only 3.

Comment: That's fairly contrived though(you wouldn't really want to set properties on your simple arrays, that would in most cases be a misuse of them). I still agree with your comment, since you can use `arr.forEach(function (element) { })`, and reduce the further `arr[i]` usage to just `element`

Comment: In JavaScript `for (var i in arr)` is hugely discouraged; look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea What @MT0 wrote appears to be rather contrived.

Comment: @wei2912 absolutely right, and I know it, I don't know what drove me to write that... Deleted now, and asked the OP to accept Sacho's instead.

Answer (score 1):

You might appreciate taking advantage of some ES6 features.  You're using an object literal like a map, so why not use a real [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?  Speaking of ES6, since you're a beginner, you would benefit from taking the time to learn it now and save yourself the headache later.  As others have noted, you can accomplish finding the mode in a single for loop.

```js
const mode = (array) => {
  const map = new Map();
  let maxFreq = 0;
  let mode;

  for(const item of array) {
    let freq = map.has(item) ? map.get(item) : 0;
    freq++;

    if(freq > maxFreq) {
      maxFreq = freq;
      mode = item;
    }
    
    map.set(item, freq);
  }

  return mode;
};

const testArray = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13];
console.log(`Mode of [${testArray}] is ${mode(testArray)}.`);
```